# Is there any way in typescript to define optional field with type?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, refactoring, option-type

I need something like that:

```
interface A {
 a: SomeUtilityType<number>;
}
```

to be equivalent to:

```
interface A {
 a?: number;
}
```

I know that I can use `Optional` from 'utility-types':

```
import { Optional } from 'utility-types';

type B = Optional<A, 'a'>
```

but I need exactly usage like this:

```
interface A {
 a: SomeUtilityType<number>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking how to define optional field in interface, you can use question mark the same as in you first example

```
interface A {
 a?: SomeUtilityType<number>;
}
```

`?:` operator can be used with primitives, and any other types too